# Call function in another files

Tags: go

I don't know how I can use function in another file.

my project architecture:

```
.
├── main.go
└── src
    └── function.go

1 directory, 2 files
```

main.go

```
package main

import "src/funcrion"

func main() {
    funcrion.Display();
}
```

function.go

```
package src

import "fmt";

func Display() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World");
}
```

For start my project I use:

```
go run main.go
```

error:

```
main.go:3:8: cannot find package "src/funcrion" in any of:
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/src/funcrion (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/clementbolin/go/src/src/funcrion (from $GOPATH)
```

In first, I want to resolve this problem. In second time I want to know what is the best option for compile a real project with more 10 files for example, do I need to use Makefile? Or like in Rust go has package manager?

Comment: Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: Files can **not** be imported, only packages can.

Comment: hm and how we can import a package ? you have to change the GOPATH each time? @mkopriva

Comment: It's described in the link posted by icza.

Comment: Please focus on one question per post. How to fix your imports is completely unrelated to whether you should use a Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `import "src/funcrion"` the go compiler will try to search for this in GOPATH and GOROOT, as you see in your error message. It does not try to search in the current folder. Since it doesn't find a package with that name in either GOPATH or GOROOT, it gives you that error.

A good way to reference "the current folder" would be using go modules. On the root of your project do `$ go mod init myproject`. (replace myproject for a more appropriate name for your project)

After you do that, you can use "myproject" to reference the project folder in package names, like:

```
package main

import "myprject/src"

func main() {
    src.Display();
}
```

Also note that the import goes only up to the package name and not the file name. So, in your case, you shouldn't do `import myproject/src/function` just because you have a `function.go` file inside a `src` package.

And since your `Display` function is inside the `src` package, you refer to it simply with `src.Display()` after importing the package. No need to specify the name of the file anywhere.

You can read more about go modules here: https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Another tip is to not use `src` as a package name. In Go, it's common to not have a "src" folder, and as a package name is also not very good. For instance, see the line that reads `src.Display()`. Instinctively, i would read this as something like "the Display of the source", which has no meaning. But if instead of `src` you name your package `text`, that same line would read `text.Display()` which would read as "display some text", which is more accurate and meaningful to what the function is doing.

Comment: this is the only method that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe the package name is `src` but I see you are trying to import `src\funcrion` There is no such package called `funcrion`.

I think you should just do something like this main.go

```
package main

import "src"

func main() {
    src.Display();
}
```

or if you would like to call your src package as funcrion, then just import it like below,

`import funcrion "src"`

And make sure your file structure is as below and inside $GOPATH

```
Users
└── clementbolin
    └── go
        └── src
            ├── main.go
            └── src
                └── function.go
```

Comment: Ok, but my goal it's to create a project not inside the $GOPATH